# AngularJS ui-sref not redirecting to state

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

For some reason I cannot redirect to the next state. 
genAPISettings.view.html only contains:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

The controller only contains this:

```
app.controller('AdminDashboardGeneralAPISettingsController', ['$scope', 
'$state', 'llApi', function ($scope, $state, llApi) {

}]);
```

The state:

```
.state('dashboardContainer.GeneralAPISettings', {
    url: 'GeneralAPISettings',
    templateUrl: 'views/AdminDashboard/genAPISettings/genAPISettings.view.html',
    controller: 'AdminDashboardGeneralAPISettingsController'
  }
```

Using `$state.go("dashboardContainer.GeneralAPISettings", {});` only shows me a flash of redirecting to the state, but then quickly redirects me to the precious state. Using `<a ui-sref = "dashboardContainer.GeneralAPISettings">General API</a>` does not redirect the page at all. However, changing the url manually to /GeneralAPISettings does correctly change to this state.

Comment: Can you post all your states? Possibly something conflicting.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: My app.routes.js contains 286 lines of code, however using the search function to search for "dashboardContainer.GeneralAPISettings", only shows 1 result.

Comment: Console shows no errors upon trying to change the state or on manually accessing /GeneralAPISettings

Comment: The <a ui-sref = "dashboardContainer.GeneralAPISettings">General API</a> is in /src/components/dashboardContainer/dashboardContainer.view.html the GeneralAPISettings is in: /src/components/AdminDashboard/genAPISettings/genAPISettings.view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have an ui-sref on the container, causing that sref to trigger instead of the one that you wanted.

For example, if your code was like this:

```
<div ui-sref="state1"><a ui-sref"state2">Link</a></div>
```

When clicking on the Link, you might expect to go to state2, but instead go to state1.

Source: I've encountered a similar problem.

Comment: This was exactly the problem, thank you so much! The <a> was inside of an accordion-group which apparently also had an ui-sref.